# CSS3 circle transforming

Tags: css, geometry

I have this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/repoo0fz/
I have this css code:

```
.menubutton{
     height:90px;
     width:180px;
     border-radius: 180px 180px 0 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 180px 180px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 180px 180px 0 0;
    float:left;
padding:0px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-bottom:0px;
font-family:courier new;
font-size:20px;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s; /* Safari */
    transition: height 0.5s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    line-height: 90px; 
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.menubutton:hover{
     height:180px;
     border-radius: 180px 180px;
     -moz-border-radius: 180px 180px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 180px 180px;
}
```

But the transformation is not as i want to. It looks weird when it is going from a half circle to a complete circle. It does not expand from a half circle but more from a oval one. I just want the last half of the circle.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it like this, changing the transition from height to all `transition: all 0.5s;`:

```css
.menubutton {
  height: 90px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px 180px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 180px 180px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 180px 180px 0 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: courier new;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.menubutton:hover {
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px 180px;
  -moz-border-radius: 180px 180px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 180px 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubutton" style="background:#46B29D;">Menu1</div>
<div class="menubutton" style="background:#F0CA4D;">Menu2</div>
<div class="menubutton" style="background:#E37B40;">Menu3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only transitioning the height...you need to set that to `all` or at least to all the properties that are changing

```css
.menubutton {
  height: 90px;
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px 180px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 180px 180px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 180px 180px 0 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: courier new;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menubutton:hover {
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px 180px;
  -moz-border-radius: 180px 180px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 180px 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubutton" style="background:#46B29D;">Menu1</div>
<div class="menubutton" style="background:#F0CA4D;">Menu2</div>
<div class="menubutton" style="background:#E37B40;">Menu3</div>
```